# How to use unknown dimension in ops calculations with TF

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, theano

For example > I've an Theano code, which works (T == Theano):

```
N = input.shape[0]  # input has shape wrt TF (?, num)
mse = T.sum(T.square(ytarg - ypred)) / N
```

I don't really know how to use variable N in TF op's calculation if it's an unknown dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tensorflow you don't need to know the number of element you'll process during graph execution. You have to delegate this task to tensorflow, using the [`tf.reduce_*`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#reduction) operations.

> Reduction
>
> TensorFlow provides several operations that you can use to perform common math computations that reduce various dimensions of a tensor.

The MSE function you defined in Theano can be defined in Tensorlow easily;

```
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(tf.sub(ytarg, ytarg), 2.0))
```

Comment: Thx for this explanation!